# How to plot day and month

Tags: python, date, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a chart of a daily trend over time.

[image: Price Over Time]

The year is not relevant here and I want to show only day and month. I know you can show year and month but that is not the case.

I tried to create a new variable called "Day_Month":

```
import datetime as dt
df['Day'] =  df['date'].dt.day
df['Month'] =  df['date'].dt.month
df['Day_Month'] = df['Day'].astype(str) + "-" +
```

but it's not possible to plot it as a string nor to convert it to date type.

eventually, I would like my chart to look like this:

[image: Final Price chart]

Comment: Have you looked at [matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter)?

Answer (score 8):

The answer I found is:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(date, price , label="Price")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
```