# how to create a tidy x-axis of datetime indexes of a data for my plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a dataframe which its index is of type datetime (like `2018-05-29 08:20:00`).

I slice the data based on **last hour** and **last day** and **last week**  and **last month** and then I plot them.

The data is collected every **one minuet**. So, the index of each row differs only one minute.

When I plot the data for last hour, the x axis is plotted like:

[image]

Or, for the last month it is like:

[image]

which is clean and readable. But, when I plot the last day data the x-axis index is like:

[image]

Why it is overlapped? how to fix it?

the codes to plot these time frames are the same, just the given dataframe is changed:

```
self.canvas.axes.plot(df_day.index, df_day.loc[:, item], linestyle="None", marker='.')
                      # or df_month or df_week or df_hour
```

how to make a the x-axis index as the format that I want?
I want it to be printed as `hour:minute` for last hour, or `day hour:minute` for last day.

I tried the links, but none of them helped:

- [Customizing Ticks](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html)
- [matplotlib: how to prevent x-axis labels from overlapping each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515471/matplotlib-how-to-prevent-x-axis-labels-from-overlapping-each-other)

I tried

```
self.canvas.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(self.major_formatter, self.canvas.axes.get_xticklabels())

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_formatter(x, pos):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x.day / 1e3)
```

but it returned `int46` in `x` variable, so it wasn't helping.

Comment: Check out `autofmt_xdate` https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/_modules/matplotlib/figure.html

Comment: @DavidHoffman it only rotates the x-indexes. it's good for the overlapping problem, thanks but how to define my own formats? btw, link is broken(error 404)

Comment: Check [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate) out. You can specify the format as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the first answer to [How to plot day and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975878/how-to-plot-day-and-month) which is also an answer from question owner I found the solution:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.plot(date, price , label="Price")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
```

or in my case:

```
self.canvas.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b'))
```

from [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes¶](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), one can learn about formats of dates and times.